# How to multiple a digit in a string by its position in the string in python

Tags: python

For instance if I had 3456789 I would want the sum to = (3x1) + (4x2) + (5x3) + (6x4) + (7x5) etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use enumerate to get an index along with each character and the sum function to add up the products:

```
sum(int(digit)*pos for pos,digit in enumerate("3456789",1)) # 196
```

Comment: cool, I have used python for many years and had no idea that you could offset the index of `enumerate()`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few hints without directly answering your question, since it looks like a homework assignment:

## How to loop through characters in a string

```py
for i, c in enumerate(your_string):
    print("pos %d is char %s" % (i, c))
```

## How to convert a string representing an integer to an integer

```py
x_str = '1'
x_int = int(x_str)
```

## How to compute sum of a function called on elements in an array (or other iterable):

This code computes the sum of each value squared:

```py
elems = [ 10, 15, 20, 25 ]

value = 0
for index, elem in enumerate(elems):
    value = elem * elem
print("Sum of products of %s is: %d" % (elems, value))
```

Alternatively you can do this:

```py
value = sum(map(lambda x: x*x, elems))
```